# How to get the actual light reflectance vector?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

The `texture coordinate` node has an output called "`reflection`". But this "`reflection`" output only gives us the reflection of a perfectly sharp mirror. So if I have e.g. a diffuse shader or a glossy shader with the roughness set toany value other than 0 the vector the `texture coordinate` node gives as "`reflection`" is not really the vector that the actual light ray got reflected.

How do I get the actual light reflectance vector?

**Edit:**

Here I have included a sample .blend file:

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't that exactly the behavior of a ray? Angle of incidence == angle of reflection? And a light beam/ray has always only exactly one reflection. Diffusity only comes about when many rays are reflected differently at different coordinates due to the surface property, right?

Comment: `Angle of incidence == angle of reflection?` Yes and No. Yes because in microfacet theory this happens on a microscopic scale, but here's the problem: When you set e.g. a glossy shader roughness to anything other than 0 it randomizes the shading normal about which the reflection occurs. The Texture coordinate reflection output can't do that and therefore always calculates the reflection vector using the unmodified shading normal.

Comment: But then I would rather guess that even in microscopic scales there is always only one ray, and that the diffusivity is rather a trick of the shader, because never so many rays can be generated as it is the case in reality, right?

Comment: What I want is the reflection vector that was calcuated using the modified shading normal.

Comment: `But then I would rather guess that even in microscopic scales there is always only one ray, and that the diffusivity is rather a trick of the shader, because never so many rays can be generated as it is the case in reality, right?` Yes and I want the vector representing that ray.

Comment: Yes, but that's what I meant ;-): this vector always stays the same, no matter how the shader then tricks around with it and builds diffusivity around it ....or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: No this vector is different for every sample. If it were the same you would just get a scewed sharp reflection.

Comment: So you would like to have the vector of a single sample (Which again depend on renderer)?

Comment: Cycles. EEVEE doesn't do path tracing.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is not possible with shader nodes. It would also be highly dependent on the particular ray and sample that is being evaluated. A particular pixel / coordinate would possibly have many different vectors. I don't think OSL would help here either. Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to use this for, so we could suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: I have a 3D procedural shape which I can only visualize using a volume shader. For this I use the Principled volume shader. You can imagine that I have an inside of the shape and an outside of the shape. To make the shape look like a solid instead of a volume I use a very high density value (about 1000000). The problem I now face is that Principled volume scatters the light diffusely, so I can't get sharp reflections. If I can somehow drive the behaviour of the shader depending on the real reflection vector I could maybe achieve sharp relfections.

Comment: I will now try to upload a sample .blend file.

Comment: I might be missing some context information, but wouldn't a *Volume to Mesh* node or modifier work?